# Database Design: use a non-key as a FK?

Tags: mysql, data-modeling, database-design

Say I have the following table:

```
TABLE: widget
 - widget_id (not null, unique, auto-increment)
 - model_name (PK)
 - model_year (PK)
```

`model_name` and `model_year` make up a composite key. Is there any problem to using `widget_id` as a FK in another table?

Comment: Did you tried it at least? What errors did you get? Should SO try your source code for you?

Comment: @eisberg - yes, I did try to model this in MySQL workbench. It worked. Doesn't mean there isn't a problem.

Comment: @cjrh - I know it's not defined as a key, but it's basically got the same properties of a key. Is there a rule that FKs must be defined as PKs in the table it comes from?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: in most DB engines, it is not enforced.  However, you want to be _really_ strict on how tables refer to each other for the purpose of staying sane.

Comment: @cjrh - which DB engines are you thinking of? The ones I know of enforce unique constraints by applying an index. A unique index on a table is a key.

Comment: @cjrh - how to I related to a table that has a composite key? I need to have another table refer to a specific row in `widget` table. However, with it having a composite key, I don't know how to do it. That is why I am trying to add `widget_id`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: the constraints are enforced if you add constraints.  If you just make two tables, load them up in code and pretend like a field in one table is an FK to a field in another table, then nothing stops you from doing that (yes, people actually do this stuff in the wild).  That's all I meant.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: Now I understand!  The answer is very simple: you have to add both PK fields to the _other_ table as the complete FK reference.   This is always what is required when you have composite PKs.

Comment: Added an answer to make the explanation explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key is any number of columns that can be used to uniquely identify each row within the table.

In the example you've shown, your widget table has two keys:

- model_name, model_year
- widget_id

In standard SQL, a foreign key may reference any declared key on the referenced table (either primary key or unique). I'd need to check MySQLs compliance.

---

From MySQL reference manual on [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.

---

As an alternative, if you wish to use the composite key from your referencing table, you'd have two columns in that table that correspond to model_name and model_year, and would then declare your foreign key constraint as:

```
ALTER TABLE OtherTable ADD CONSTRAINT
     FK_OtherTable_Widgets (model_name,model_year)
     references Widgets (model_name,model_Year).
```

---

Re InnoDB vs MyISAM, in the docs for [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

> The FOREIGN KEY and REFERENCES clauses are supported by the InnoDB storage engine, which implements ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY (...) REFERENCES ... (...). See Section 13.6.4.4, “FOREIGN KEY Constraints”. For other storage engines, the clauses are parsed but ignored. The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. See Section 12.1.17, “CREATE TABLE Syntax”. The reason for accepting but ignoring syntax clauses is for compatibility, to make it easier to port code from other SQL servers, and to run applications that create tables with references. See Section 1.8.5, “MySQL Differences from Standard SQL”.

Comment: MySQL Workbench did not complain when I did this. Does it mean it's OK?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie - I would say so.

Comment: I am using MyISAM (default in MySQL Workbench). Should I be using InnoDB?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie - MyISAM (by my understanding) doesn't enforce foreign key constraints anyway. It lets you run the statements, but they have no effect (other than documentation).

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience specific to my-sql, but with database-modeling in general

It is really important to understand the difference between primary and secondary keys.
Even if many db (I know for sure Oracle does) permit to specify an unique (simple or composite) key as the FK target, this is not considered a best practice. Use the PK instead.

FK to a secondary key should be used imo only to relate to tables that are not under your control.

In your specific case, I would certainly FK to widget_id: that is because the widget_id should be your PK, and the composite  only made unique (and not null of course). This leads to better performance in mane cases, as you join only one column in queries, and is generally considered a best practice (google 'surrogate key' for more info)

Comment: @Whisper - I don't see `widget_id` as my PK. I need `model_id` and `model_year` to be unique as a pair (that's why they are a composite key). If I remove them as PKs, I could end up with incorrect data. I'm trying to add `widget_id` because I need to be able to refer to a specific row in that table. With composite key, I don't know how to do it. So, I'm trying to add `widget_id`.

Comment: I'm not saying that the index should be: 
unique(model_id),unique(model_year), but
unique(model_id,model_year), in this case the db will create an unique composite index exactly equivalent to your composite pk

Comment: Of course, the counterpoint to "join only one column in queries" when using natural keys is "avoid the join if the data sought is the natural key"

Comment: Well, my sentence was 'is considered a best practice', not 'I consider...' :)

Indeed I prefer using natural keys, even if composite. But ORM often find composite keys problematic and leading to 'slow' performance.

If natural keys are used, then there is no need at all for surrogate widget_id at all.

Comment: Wishper: "It is really important to understand the difference between primary and secondary keys". In principle there is no difference at all between primary keys and other candidate keys. In relational modelling terms all keys are equal. So the difference is only what you choose to make it and doesn't have to be important at all.

Comment: @dportas:  In principle, you're correct.  In practicality, with some databases, the data when loaded is ordered on the disk by the primary key.  Inserted data is put in defined gaps or at the end.  So, for those databases, it's important for performance that the primary key be the most used access key.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will create an index on the column if there isn't one it can use:

> InnoDB requires indexes on foreign
>   keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not
>   require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an
>   index where the foreign key columns
>   are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order. Such an index is created
>   on the referencing table automatically
>   if it does not exist. (This is in
>   contrast to some older versions, in
>   which indexes had to be created
>   explicitly or the creation of foreign
>   key constraints would fail.)
>   index_name, if given, is used as
>   described previously.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two tables.  The first table looks like this:

```
TABLE: widget
 - model_name (PK)
 - model_year (PK)
 - widget_id (not null, unique, auto-increment)
```

If you want to make another table that refers to unique records in the first table, it should look something like this:

```
TABLE B: sprocket
 - part_number (PK)
 - blah
 - blah
 - model_name_widget (FK to widget)
 - model_year_widget (FK to widget)
 - blah
```

With compound primary keys, you have to include all key fields in your FK references to make sure that you are uniquely specifying a record.